# Access core data from widget extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I am trying to read core data attributes in today widget extension. I have searched many website and questions here but I couldn't find a solution ! So far I added app group to my app and then change this line in `App Delegate` :

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // file. This code uses a directory named "compony.AppName" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()
```

to :

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL? = {
    return NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.myDomain.appgroupID") ?? nil
}()
```

so what is the next step ? how can I access to context entity and etc... from widget center  ? I would be grateful if some body help me out.

I have only one `entity` with several `attributes`.

**EDIT**

- I create a `CoreDataStack.swift` and copied all core data files from `AppDelegate` to new file.
- Added my data model to widget extension :

[image]

- In extension `viewDidLoad` I tired to retrieve data from model but nothing happens when I run the widget :

  ```
   context  = CoreDataStack.defaultStack.managedObjectContext

  do {

      request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")
      results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
      print(results.count)

      if results.count > 0 {

          for item in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

              let name = item.valueForKey("title")

              print(name!)
          }

      }//end if


  } catch {

      print("there is an error for saving")
  }
  ```

Comment: Have you followed all the needed steps? e.g. https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/sharing-data-between-apps-and-their-extenstions/

Comment: @LorenzoBoaro this sit the most silly tutorial I ever seen ! the title is about core data and today extension but when you follow the last step ! it said , Core data is not always good !!!!!!!! use NSUserDefualts !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since widgets do not have an app delegate, you might want to move your core data stack code out of the app delegate class in your main app.

I usually use a class called `CoreDataStack`. Just copy all of the methods into this new class, changing `lazy` to `static`:

```
class CoreDataStack {
    static var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL? = { ... }()
    static var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = { ... }()
    static var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = { ... }()
    static var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = { ... }()
}
```

As these are all `static` variables, you can use the following syntax to access the managed context:

```
let ctx = CoreDataStack.managedObjectContext
```

...instead of the typical access through your app delegate.

You should add this file to both your main app target and your widget target, using the right sidebar under "Target Membership. This way, you will access your Core Data stack the same way in both places. You'll want to do the same with all of your models to ensure they are available in the extension.

Comment: @Mc.Lover so sorry...I didn't get a notification for your comment. Make sure you are using the CoreDataStack class directly, and not instantiating an instance of it. If you pastebin your class and tell me where it's erroring i might be able to help in a few minutes

Comment: Also make sure you didn't forget the () at the end of each static variable declaration

Comment: The class is NOT a singleton (although that is a possible solution). You don't access it with CoreDataStack.defaultStack.managedObjectContext, you just use CoreDataStack.managedObjectContext @Mc.Lover

Comment: If you give me half an hour I can make a sample project. What Xcode version? @Mc.Lover

Comment: Wow that's great ! Xcode 7.3.1 , Swift 2.2, just in case I need to use that core data in both widget and watch app extension. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @Mc.Lover https://www.dropbox.com/s/0r8x0v0vb2hxipn/SampleCoreDataAppWithExtension.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please take note: The Core Data Model, CoreDataStack, and the model class files are all members of both the main app target and the extension target.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118461/discussion-between-santa-claus-and-mc-lover).

Comment: can you help me out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636146/retrieve-data-from-core-data-in-watch-os

Comment: @Mc.Lover Sorry, I was out of town and wasn't able to respond. Did you get an answer?

Comment: That's oK ;) , yes , but it doesn't work properly ! it seems we cannot user core data in Watch OS ! instead we have to send its attributes as string, but it doesn't work properly ! I am using `WatchConnectivity` Why we cannot use core data just like widget !! would you send me an email to share my code with you ? `momeks[at]gmail[dot]com`